# Execute AWS Datasync task using step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, state-machine, aws-step-functions, aws-datasync

We have a requirement to create a state machine which includes to datasync tasks followed by each other. These datasync tasks are already created and now I want to execute it using step functions one after another. What is the resource to execute a datasync task.
For eg: For executing a Glue Job we give Resource:arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync

What Resource string is used for executing a datasync task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) integrates with [AWS DataSync](https://aws.amazon.com/datasync/) using [AWS SDK Service Integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/supported-services-awssdk.html#supported-services-awssdk-list). The `Resource` string will be of the form `arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:datasync:<api-action>`

The easiest way to find this sort of information is with [Workflow Studio](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/workflow-studio.html). As you can see in the image below, it allows you to search through available services and api actions to find what you need, then just drag it into your workflow.

[image]

Step Functions does not have an [Optimized Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-supported-services.html) for DataSync and therefore only supports the [Request Response integration pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html#connect-default). As such, I suspect you will want to use the Job Poller pattern (Workflow Studio helps you here as well) to start the task execution then monitor for completion.

[image]

For easier re-use, you might want to implement this in a state machine that you can then reuse by calling it from other state machines when needed. [This blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/orchestrating-aws-glue-crawlers-using-aws-step-functions/) goes into detail on how to do a similar thing with Glue Crawler, but much of it will be applicable.

Comment: Thanks Justin . You are savior 

Comment: Glad it was useful, happy to help!

Comment: Hey Justin , I'm using the TaskToken feature for a datasync task to get completed. I have added waitForTaskToken at the end in the resource but how do I use TaskToken feature in state machine definition wrt to Datasync. Do you have any idea? @Justin